# WCF Web Service with mutual authentication certificates failing on client chain trust validation

Tags: wcf, ssl-certificate, wcf-security, mutual-authentication

I'm developping a proof of concept for a WCF web service using SSL and certificates for mutual authentication.

So, I have 2 certificates both provided by a valid certification authority (these are production certificates, not development). Here are the chains and the store locations for the certificates :

> **Server Certificate Chain**
>
> - Issuer Root CA
>
>   - Intermediate 1 CA
>
>     - Server Authentication certificate
>
> I don't know if this detail is important or not : server certificate is a wildcard certificate for the domain (**.mydomain.com*)
>
> **Client Certificate Chain**
>
> - Issuer Root CA
>
>   - Intermediate 2 CA
>
>     - Client Authentication certificate
>
> *Issuer Root CA is common root CA for both certificates.*
>
> *Intermediates certificates are differents.*
>
> **Store Location**
>
> Issuer Root CA have been imported into *Trusted Root CA* on both server and client machines
>   Intermediate CA 1 & 2 have been imported into *Intermediate CA* on both server and client
>   Issuer and intermediates certificates have both public keys only.
>
> Server certificate have been imported into *Personal* on server machine. This certificate have a private key.
>   Server certificate have been imported into *Personal* on client machine. This certificate have a public key only.
>   Client authentication certificate have been imported into *Personal* on both server and clients machines. These certificates have both private keys.

I created a simple WCF application project hosted in IIS 8.5 with framework C# 4.0.
I use the example classes provided by default at the project creation, I have just renamed it into *DemoService.svc*.
Then, I created the client (I use a winform application for target users to have a graphical interface to view results) and add the web service reference.

Then, I modified the service configuration to set up mutual authentication. All is done via web.config :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="demoServiceBehavior">
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups"></serviceAuthorization>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="*.mydomain.com"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true"
                trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
              <certificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                findValue="myservice.mydomain.com"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="demoServiceBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="WcfMutualAuthenticationServiceDemo.DemoService" relativeAddress="DemoService.svc" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfMutualAuthenticationServiceDemo.DemoService" behaviorConfiguration="demoServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://myservice.mydomain.com/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="demoServiceEndpoint"
                  address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="demoServiceBinding"
                  contract="WcfMutualAuthenticationServiceDemo.IDemoService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I modified the client configuration to set up mutual authentication too :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="demoClientBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
              findValue="myservice.dekra-automotivesolutions.com"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="demoClientBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://myservice.mydomain.com/DemoService.svc"
                behaviorConfiguration="demoClientBehavior"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="demoClientBinding"
                contract="DemoServiceValidReference.IDemoService"
                name="demoServiceEndpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I call the web service via the client, it return an exception :

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   'myservice.mydomain.com'. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create
>   SSL/TLS secure channel.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

After investigation, I found an entry in the server's event viewer :

> Handling an exception. Exception details:
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: The
>   X.509 certificate CN=myservice.mydomain chain building failed. The
>   certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified.
>   Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A
>   certification chain processed correctly, but one of the CA
>   certificates is not trusted by the policy provider.
>
> at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateChain.Build(X509Certificate2
>   certificate)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator.ChainTrustValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2
>   certificate)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509SecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateTokenCore(SecurityToken
>   token)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateToken(SecurityToken
>   token)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsChannelListener`1.CreateSecurityProperty(X509Certificate2
>   certificate, WindowsIdentity identity, String authType)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsChannelListener`1.ProcessAuthentication(IHttpAuthenticationContext
>   authenticationContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnProcessAuthentication()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.ProcessAuthentication()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.Authenticate()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()

Regarding this exception, I found that the issue is on the chain validation of the client authentication certificate, but I don't know why.
At this point, I'm stuck !
I don't know what's wrong with my certificates, and I don't know how to find a solution.

I truly hope that someone could help me fixing this issue.

**Edit :**
We have tested with another client certificate for the certification chain to be the same on server and client certificates, it don't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was found today : configuration is OK on client and server.
It was a misconfiguration on the IIS server certificate mapping, the functionnality was not configured but not enabled.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer yourself. Can I ask you a question? The WSDL have Asymmetric binding element?